# Cayley's formula

Tags: combinatorics

[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8T0O.png)

Hope someone can help with the image above please? There are three non-isomorphic trees available on 5 vertices as shown in the image. The first tree in the picture can be labelled in 5 ways - which I can see using (n!/(k!(n-k)!)

I am told the second and third can be labelled in 60 ways. Could someone explain how the figure of 60 is arrived at?

Many Thanks

Blobfish

Answer (score 1):

In general you get $5!=120$ ways to label 5 vertices of course.

For the middle example switching the label of the middle and left branch just creates an isomporphic tree. Switching any other labels creates a deifferent tree. So you get $5!/2=60$ labelings in total.

For the third tree the argument is basically the same. You can swap both branches to get an isomorphic tree. Therefore we again get $5!/2=60$.